# How to make a data frame with a lot of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

im trying to make a data frame from a lot of dictionaries so i have a list that is full of dictionaries

```
dictlist
```

thats the ouput of my list

```
[{'subject': projectmanagementplan, 'link': [provides], 'object': areas},
 {'subject': highlevelprojectdescriptions,
  'link': [highlevelrequirements],
  'object': register},
 {'subject': sstakeholders, 'link': [provides], 'object': riskattitudes},
 {'subject': planriskmanagementprocess,
  'link': [include],
  'object': riskattitudes},
 {'subject': tolerances, 'link': [describe], 'object': organization},
 {'subject': planriskmanagementprocess,
  'link': [include],
  'object': riskcategories},
 {'subject': terms,
  'link': [authoritylevels],
  'object': learnedanalyticaltechniques},
 {'subject': riskstatementformats, 'link': [templates], 'object': '-'},
 {'subject': responsibilities,
  'link': [authoritylevels],
  'object': learnedanalyticaltechniques}]
```

so my list contains this which is a lot of dictionaries
i want to make a dataframe with three columns (subject,link, object)
i tried this code

```
output=pd.Dataframe()
for j in dictlist:
    output.append(j,ignore_index=True)
```

but it doesnt work all i get is an empty dataframe

Comment: 1- your list of dictionaries is not valid python (or you failed to explicit the variables), 2- what is the expected output?

Comment: my expected output  is a dataframe with 3 columns subject link and object

Comment: The solution is so simple, you could be forgiven for not trying it: if you list is `xs`, all you need is `DataFrame(xs)` - of course, for that to work, your dictionary does need to be an actual valid Python dictionary, the example you shared isn't. (unless all those unquoted words are actually meant to be variables, but that seems unlikely)

Comment: i edited the code , i dont get it how its not valid python when i do ```for i in dictlist: 
   print(type(i))```  i get```<class 'dict'>``` for each one of the list elements

Comment: anyway i tried your solution and it worked DataFrame(dictlist) worked thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a small sample of your data, and assuming that the unquoted words are actually strings, the answer is simply `pd.DataFrame(dictlist)`. If that doesn't work for you, then something else is wrong and you'll need to provide more information.

```py
In [3]: dictlist
Out[3]:
[{'subject': 'projectmanagementplan', 'link': ['provides'], 'object': 'areas'},
 {'subject': 'highlevelprojectdescriptions',
  'link': ['highlevelrequirements'],
  'object': 'register'},
 {'subject': 'sstakeholders', 'link': ['provides'], 'object': 'riskattitudes'},
 {'subject': 'planriskmanagementprocess',
  'link': ['include'],
  'object': 'riskattitudes'}]

In [4]: pd.DataFrame(dictlist)
Out[4]:
                        subject                     link                       object
0         projectmanagementplan               [provides]                        areas
1  highlevelprojectdescriptions  [highlevelrequirements]                     register
2                 sstakeholders               [provides]                riskattitudes
3     planriskmanagementprocess                [include]                riskattitudes
```

Comment: yess this works i tried it from @Grismar comment and it worked thanks anyway but can you explain why everyone is saying its invalid python but when i do ```for i in dictlist:    print(type(i))``` i get <class 'dict'> for each element of the list

Comment: Nobody is saying your `for` loop is invalid. We were all trying to explain that the data you provided was invalid.

Comment: E.g., `'subject': projectmanagementplan` is invalid ***unless*** `projectmanagementplan` is already a defined variable. We were trying to point out that your data should look like `'subject': 'projectmanagementplan'`.

Comment: oh i get it sorry for that, its because i copied the output of printing the list